# tf.train.string_input_producer behavior in a loop

Tags: tensorflow

The following snippet has been taken from the TensorFlow 0.12 API documentation

```py
def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
      filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
  example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
  # min_after_dequeue defines how big a buffer we will randomly sample
  #   from -- bigger means better shuffling but slower start up and more
  #   memory used.
  # capacity must be larger than min_after_dequeue and the amount larger
  #   determines the maximum we will prefetch.  Recommendation:
  #   min_after_dequeue + (num_threads + a small safety margin) * batch_size
  min_after_dequeue = 10000
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
  return example_batch, label_batch
```

The question I have might be very basic for a regular TensorFlow user, but I am an absolute beginner. The question is the following :

- `tf.train.string_input_producer` creates a queue for holding the filenames. As the `input_pipeline()` is called over and over again during training, how will it be ensured that everytime the same queue is used ? I guess, it is important since, if different calls to `input_pipeline()` result in a creation of a new queue, there does not seem to be a way to ensure that different images are picked everytime  and epoch counter and shuffling can be properly maintained.

Answer (score 3):

The `input_pipeline` function only creates the part of a (usually larger) graph that is responsible for producing batches of data. If you were to call `input_pipeline` twice - for whatever reason - you would be creating two different queues indeed.

In general, the function `tf.train.string_input_producer` actually creates a queue *node* (or *operation*) in the currently active graph (which is the default graph unless you specify something different). `read_my_file_format` then reads from that queue and sequentially produces single "example" tensors, while `tf.train.shuffle_batch` then batches these into bundles of length `batch_size` each.

However, the output of `tf.train.shuffle_batch`, two Tensors here that are returned from the `input_pipeline` function, only really takes on a (new) value when it is evaluated under a session. If you evaluate these tensors multiple times, they will contain different values - taken, through `read_my_file_format`, from files listed in the input queue.

Think of it like so:

```py
X_batch, Y_batch = input_pipeline(..., batch_size=100)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variable_initializer())   
   tf.train.start_queue_runners()

   # get the first 100 examples and labels
   X1, Y1 = sess.run((X_batch, Y_batch))

   # get the next 100 examples and labels
   X2, Y2 = sess.run((X_batch, Y_batch))

   # etc.
```

The boilerplate code to get it running is a bit more complex, e.g. because queues need to actually be started and stopped in the graph, because they will throw a `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` when they run dry, etc.
A more complete example could look like this:

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
   X_batch, Y_batch = input_pipeline(..., batch_size=100)

   prediction = inference(X_batch)
   optimizer, loss = optimize(prediction, Y_batch)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
   init = tf.group(tf.local_variable_initializer(),
                   tf.global_variable_initializer())
   sess.run(init)

   # start the queue runners
   threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

   try:
       while not coord.should_stop():

           # now you're really indirectly querying the
           # queue; each iteration will see a new batch of
           # at most 100 values.
           _, loss = sess.run((optimizer, loss))

           # you might also want to do something with
           # the network's output - again, this would
           # use a fresh batch of inputs
           some_predicted_values = sess.run(prediction)

   except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
       print('Training stopped, input queue is empty.')
   finally:
       coord.request_stop()

   # stop the queue(s)
   coord.request_stop()
   coord.join(threads)
```

For a deeper understanding, you might want to look at the [Reading data](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/) documentation.