# Tensorflow and reading binary data properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to properly read in my own binary data to Tensorflow based on Fixed length records section of [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data), and by looking at the read_cifar10 function [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py). Mind you I am new to tensorflow, so my understanding may be off.

**My Data**

My files are binary with float32 type. The first 32 bit sample is the label, and the remaining 256 samples are the data. I want to reshape the data at the end to a [2, 128] matrix.

**My Code So far:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os


def read_data(filename_queue):
    item_type = tf.float32
    label_items = 1
    data_items = 256

    label_bytes = label_items * item_type.size
    data_bytes = data_items * item_type.size
    record_bytes = label_bytes + data_bytes

    reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    record_data = tf.decode_raw(value, item_type)

    # labels = tf.cast(tf.strided_slice(record_data, [0], [label_items]), tf.int32)
    label = tf.strided_slice(record_data, [0], [label_items])
    data0 = tf.strided_slice(record_data, [label_items], [label_items + data_items])
    data = tf.reshape(data0, [2, data_items/2])
    return data, label


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"  # Set GPU device
    datafiles = ['train_0000.dat', 'train_0001.dat']
    num_epochs = 2
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(datafiles, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
    data, label = read_data(filename_queue)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)
        (x, y) = read_data(filename_queue)
        print(y.eval())
```

This code hands at the `print(y.eval())`, but I fear I have much bigger issues than that.

**Question:**

When I execute this, I get a `data` and `label` tensor returned. The problem is I don't quite understand how to actually read the data from the tensor. For example, I understand the autoencoder example [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/autoencoder.py), however this has a `mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)` function that is called to read the next batch. Do I need to write that for my function, or is it handled by something internal to my `read_data()` function. If I need to write that function, what does it look like?

Are their any other obvious things I'm missing? My goal in using this method is to reduce I/O overhead, and not store all of the data in memory, since my file are quite large.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are pretty much done. At this point you need to:

1) Write your neural network model `model` which is supposed to take your data and return a label.

2) Write your cost function `C` which takes the network prediction and the true label and gives you a cost.

3) Choose and optimizer.

4) Put everything together:

```
opt = tf.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
datafiles = ['train_0000.dat', 'train_0001.dat']
num_epochs = 2


with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)    
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(datafiles, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
    data, label = read_data(filename_queue)
    example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
  [data, label], batch_size=128)

    y_pred = model(data)
    loss = C(label, y_pred)
```

After which you iterate and minimize the loss with:

```
opt.minimize(loss)
```

See also [tf.train.string_input_producer behavior in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909915/tf-train-string-input-producer-behavior-in-a-loop#41915871) for related information.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm still a little confused. My datafiles variable is an input to ``tf.train.string_input_producer`` so I'm not sure if iterating over that is the right move. The number of epochs was an input to the filename_queue. Are you suggesting that I don't need the ``tf.train.string_input_producer``?

Comment: Sorry, I indeed skipped over `tf.train.string_input_producer`, you still need it.

Comment: Edited the answer to take that into account.